# How to convert back-slashes to forward-slashes?

Tags: python, replace

I am working in python and I need to convert this:

```
C:\folderA\folderB to C:/folderA/folderB
```

I have three approaches:

```
dir = s.replace('\\','/')

dir = os.path.normpath(s) 

dir = os.path.normcase(s)
```

In each scenario the output has been

```
C:folderAfolderB
```

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong, any suggestions?

Comment: Why do you need to convert it? You could use `r'C:\folderA\folderB'`

Comment: Well `s.replace('//', '\')` shouldn't even run. The `'\'` is invalid, you need to escape backslashes. The correct way would be `s.replace('/', '\\')`. Right now when it's running it will just give you `\f` which is a linefeed character.

Comment: I think I posted wrong i believe my original string was dir = s.replace('//','\'). I will verify and update the post if thats the case.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Your specific problem is the order and escaping of your `replace` arguments, should be

```
s.replace('\\', '/')
```

Then there's:

```
posixpath.join(*s.split('\\'))
```

Which on a *nix platform is equivalent to:

```
os.path.join(*s.split('\\'))
```

But don't rely on that on Windows because it will prefer the platform-specific separator. Also:

> Note that on Windows, since there is a current directory for each
>   drive, os.path.join("c:", "foo") represents a path relative to the
>   current directory on drive C: (c:foo), not c:\foo.

Comment: I just printed the results from my input and noticed the backslashes didn't exist which explains my output. This is was a great explanation though! Thanks!

Comment: Good explanation. However it solves partially the problem, because '\t','\n','\b','\s',.. special characters in general are identified, and therefore are not transformed into '/t','/n'... For example 'C:\program\newdirectory' is transformed into 'C:/program\newdirectory

Comment: Won't this be a problem on *nix platforms, because \ is allowed in filenames there? So a path `foo/bar\baz` will become `foo/bar/baz`, which is probably not what we want. I think using `os.sep` like in @Numabyte's answer is a better cross-platform solution

Answer (score 80):

I recently found this and thought worth sharing:

```
import os

path = "C:\\temp\myFolder\example\\"
newPath = path.replace(os.sep, '/')
print(newPath)  # -> C:/temp/myFolder/example/
```

Answer (score 11):

Try

```
path = '/'.join(path.split('\\'))
```

Comment: If you really want to get fancy you could use ```os.path.sep.join(...)```

Answer (score 8):

Sorry for being late to the party, but I wonder no one has suggested the pathlib-library.

**pathlib** is a module for "Object-oriented filesystem paths"

To convert from windows-style (backslash)-paths to forward-slashes (as typically for Posix-Paths) you can do so in a very verbose (AND platform-independant) fashion with pathlib:

```
import pathlib

pathlib.PureWindowsPath(r"C:\folderA\folderB").as_posix()
>>> 'C:/folderA/folderB'
```

Be aware that the example uses the string-literal "r" (to avoid having "\" as escape-char)
In other cases the path should be quoted properly (with double backslashes) "C:\\folderA\\folderB"

Comment: Thanks; I've found this to be the best answer (not sure why it's not upvoted more)

Comment: Thanks, Neil, of course I agree :-) 
Especially not having to explicitly deal with "\" and string-replaces accounts for a stable and robust solution.

Comment: Yes this is the best answer as `replace('\\', '/')` will not work when using unmodified paths coming from windows!

Answer (score 6):

Path names are formatted diﬀerently in Windows.  the solution is simple, suppose you have a path string like this:

```
data_file = "/Users/username/Downloads/PMLSdata/series.csv"
```

simply you have to change it to this: (adding r front of the path)

```
data_file = r"/Users/username/Downloads/PMLSdata/series.csv"
```

The modiﬁer r before the string tells Python that this is a raw string. In raw strings, the backslash is interpreted literally, not as an escape character.

Comment: I have `path = 'some\thing'` and then in another function I access the variable path. I wish I could do `rpath`, but it doesn't work anymore. Is there a solution for this case?

Answer (score 2):

To define the path's variable you have to add `r` initially, then add the replace statement `.replace('\\', '/')` at the end.

**for example:**

```
In>>  path2 = r'C:\Users\User\Documents\Project\Em2Lph\'.replace('\\', '/')
In>>  path2 
Out>> 'C:/Users/User/Documents/Project/Em2Lph/'
```

This solution requires no additional libraries

Comment: I have `path = 'some\thing'` and then in another function I access the variable `path`? I wish I could do `rpath`, but it doesn't work anymore. Is there a solution for this case?

Answer (score 0):

How about :

```
import ntpath
import posixpath
.
.
.
dir = posixpath.join(*ntpath.split(s))
.
.
```

Comment: Avoid code-only answers please. Provide an explanation to your answer and comment the behavior the OP has.

Answer (score 0):

This can work also:

```
def slash_changer(directory):

if "\\" in directory:
    return directory.replace(os.sep, '/')
else:
    return directory
```

print(slash_changer(os.getcwd()))

Answer (score 0):

One of the problem I came across is occur when you try to change the backslash followed by and immediate integer like

```
img = "C:\folderA\folderB\61853639372.png"
```

This will cause changing the file name, to solve this use this code

```
import os

img = r"C:\folderA\folderB\61853639372.png"
img = os.path.normpath(img)
print(img)
```

by add an r prefix to the string used to indicate that it should be treated as a "raw string". Raw strings treat backslashes as literal backslashes and do not interpret escape characters.

Answer (score -1):

this is the perfect solution put the letter 'r' before the string that you want to convert to avoid all special characters likes '\t' and '\f'...
like the example below:

```
str= r"\test\hhd"

print("windows path:",str.replace("\\","\\\\"))
print("Linux path:",str.replace("\\","/"))
```

result:

```
windows path: \\test\\hhd
Linux path: /test/hhd
```