# Python - replace backslash with forward slash (Dropbox aspect)

Tags: python, path, dropbox, backslash

I have a problem, which I can't deal with. I'm trying to make my own program to send files to Dropbox, but their system doesn't allow backslashes.

When I want to send path to file like this:

`..\Users\TS\Desktop\Program\Nowy dokument tekstowy - Kopia (2).txt`

I got error:

`ErrorResponse: [400] {u'path': u"Invalid path '/..\\Users\\TS\\Desktop\\Program\\Nowy dokument tekstowy - Kopia (2).txt': character at index 3: backslash not allowed"}`

I googled for this (i.e. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4119166/replace-backslashes-with-forward-slashes-in-python) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25146960/python-convert-back-slashes-to-forward-slashes)), searched in Python's os.path docs but it didn't help me.

I mean output for this code:

`s = r'..\Users\TS\Desktop\Program\Nowy dokument tekstowy - Kopia (2).txt '
s.replace('\\', '/')
print s`

or this:

`s = r'..\Users\TS\Desktop\Program\Nowy dokument tekstowy - Kopia (2).txt '
s.replace('\\', '/')
print s`

is the same:

`..\Users\TS\Desktop\Program\Nowy dokument tekstowy - Kopia (2).txt`

I need to deal with relatives paths, not absolutes.
Any other idea how to deal with paths like this? Or maybe how to make Dropbox accepts backslashes?

EDIT: I'm using Python2.7

Comment: What if you try `s = s.replace('\\', '/')`?

Comment: You are printing the old value of `s`. You need to assign the replaced string to a variable.

Comment: Yea, I got this, it solves my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
s = r'..\Users\TS\Desktop\Program\Nowy dokument tekstowy - Kopia (2).txt '
s = s.replace('\\', '/')
print s
```

Output: `../Users/TS/Desktop/Program/Nowy dokument tekstowy - Kopia (2).txt`

Note that `s.replace()` by itself doesn't do anything. You have to assign `s = s.replace()` to have the desired effect.